# I need to communicate with multiple remote actor systems

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

Im playing with using akka.Net to develop a plugin architecture whereby each dll that contains one or more plugins is loaded into its own `AppDomain` and a new actor system is initialized ready to recieve messages from the "Host".

I become unstuck trying to get this to work with multiple plugins.

So the Host config looks like:

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
    }
    remote {
        helios.tcp {
            transport-class = ""Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote""
            applied-adapters = []
            transport-protocol = tcp
            port = 50003
            hostname = localhost
        }
    }
}
```

And the plugin config looks like:

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
    }
    remote {
        helios.tcp {
            transport-class = ""Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote""
            applied-adapters = []
            transport-protocol = tcp
            port = 50004
            hostname = localhost
    }
}
```

(there are many of these)

My question is how do i get messages from the Host to all of the plugins?

Comment: Have them register to the Host on startup, and from the host you now have their list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best recommendation is to use Akka.Cluster. Here's a well-documented example: https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples/tree/master/Cluster.WebCrawler

**Edit - removed suggestion to use dynamic port. Much better off using static ones so node reboots can be handled correctly.**

Have each plugin config use a plugin-specific port (`akka.remote.helios.tcp.port = 1231`) and then define a clustered router that talks to actor systems fulfilling specific roles.

```
/api/broadcaster {
  router = broadcast-group
  routees.paths = ["user/api"]
  cluster {
      enabled = on
      max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
      allow-local-routees = on
      use-role = crawler
  }
}
```

This router, deployed at the path `user/api/broadcaster` on some node can communicate (via the `Broadcast` routing strategy) with any actor deployed at path `user/api` on any node in the cluster with role `crawler` without needing to look up IP addresses, ports, or any of that crap.

You configure a node's clustering information via the following section in Akka.NET's config:

```
cluster {
  #manually populate other seed nodes here, i.e. "akka.tcp://lighthouse@127.0.0.1:4053"
  seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://webcrawler@127.0.0.1:4053"]
  roles = [crawler]
}
```

**Seed nodes** - has to be a well-known, statically-defined port and IP address. Read the article for an explanation on why this is important.

**Roles** - comma-delimited strings that define what this particular nodes' capabilities are. They're more like tags. You can use them inside clustered routers (like the one I showed earlier) to articulate which types of nodes you want to communicate with.

Comment: How can you get around Firewall issues with dynamic ports?

Comment: @Chris yeah, my advice on using dynamic ports here should be ammended. They're not a good fit with Akka.Cluster due to a variety of issues, firewall being one of them.